# Some folders are missing in ClawsMail

Tags: email, claws-mail

I've restarted the system and when I run Claws-Mail again some of the folders where missing, they are in `/home/kuba/Mail` directory but they are not visible in Claws-Mail. How can I make them visible again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right mouse click on the box there is menu option to find new folders.